# Hockey App - behavior after feedback

Tags: android, cordova, hockeyapp, beta-testing

I am in the process of testing out using [HockeyApp](https://hockeyapp.net) to provide an integrated feedback mechanism for a new hybrid Cordova/Android app that I plan to get into beta soon. I have inserted a few `Feedback` buttons in the app which issue a

```
hockeyapp.Feedback(null,null,true,{data:1,...})
```

which allows the user to grab a screen shot, post a few comments and send them back to me.  All very nice and straightforward thus far.  What I find peculiar is that after sending out the comments the page displayed by HockeyApp stays put with no evident way of getting back to the app itself.  I eventually tried the Back button to which it responded, perhaps - though I am not sure, by restarting the app.  Is this normal behavior or is there some way of configuring HockeyApp to shut down its feedback screen once feedback has been sent out?

I'd be most grateful for any feedback.

Comment: If it uses an inAppBrowser it might be related to the issue of not being able to close these in Cordova from js? I had this issue long time ago and don’t know if it still exists.

Comment: Also stuck with this. Quite frustrating